# Search bar that displays the results of 1 or more of the keywords entered

Tags: php, search, wordpress, buddypress, searchbar

The title might seem a bit misleading... what I mean is, for example, if I had 3 keywords to enter is a search bar (we'll call them X, Y, Z), instead of the search query displaying results which have:

> **X and Y and Z**

I would want:

> **X and/or Y and/or Z**

My search bar is the default given by buddypress, on wordpress, so I won't put the code in here because it is very long, and full of wordpress-specific parameters/variables. But as a general concept, how would I change this? What are the functions that alter this?

On a sidenote: this search bar, like most that I've seen, creates a URL of the following form:

> **http://example.com/?s=X%20Y%20Z**

Would making the change I'm looking for alter the form of the URL, or would the URL remain untouched, provided that the code interprets it differently?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You will definitely find the answer in [this blog post](http://wpmu.org/wordpress-search/) on wpmu.org.

Comment: See http://wpmu.org/wordpress-search/